# How to Create an array/structure before the Main() and initialize it in C

Tags: c, struct, initialization, global

I know in C, one way to solve the "*initializer element is not constant*" error is to create the strcuture inside the main() function. But suppose that I have an array of structs and want to use it as a global array. How can I create and initialize it?

```
struct A *b = malloc(10*sizeof(struct A)); // Want to keep the malloc
void init_A_types(struct A* t)
{
  t->elm1=0; t->elm2=1;
}
...
int Main() {
  for (k=0;k<10;k++)
  init_A_types(b+k);
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array, why don't you declare it as an array?

```
struct A {
    const char *str;
    int n;
};

struct A b[3] = {
    {
        "foo", 1
    },
    {
        "bar", 2
    },
    {
        "baz", 3
    }
};
```

If you **want** a global pointer, then **use** a global pointer:

```
struct A *b;

int main()
{
    b = malloc(sizeof(*b) * 10);

    // do stuff

    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if "10" in my example is "10000"? and I also want to malloc it on the heap.

Comment: @Computer_guy Sorry. Then you're going to type during a long period. If you want `malloc()` (***Why on Earth would you need it?***), then use a global pointer and `malloc()` it in `main()`. Really, you seem to be worrying about this too much. Use arrays for what they are for, use pointers for what they are for, and try to **do something** instead of worrying.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I made it complicated. Yes, the use of a global pointer and the malloc() it in the main() is the answer. Can you edit your main post so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: About the use of malloc(), I think some advantage of the heap over the stack could be convincing. Right?

Comment: @Computer_guy No. If you have a global array, that doesn't go to the stack.

Comment: @Computer_guy Trust me. You don't really want to dynamically allocate memory for a global, program-lifetime object. What you're doing is premature optimization.

Comment: All right. What if it normally doesn't fit the stack? I also don't understand this "that doesn't go to the stack". "doesn't" or in your opinion "shouldn't" ?

Comment: @Computer_guy Doesn't. It's generally put into the BSS or DATA segment of the executable by the compiler, since it's global. It would only be allocated on the stack if you declared it locally, inside a function.

Answer (score 2):

In your program, you could consider modifying this statement `struct A *b = malloc(10*sizeof(struct A));` to `struct A b[10];` and the rest of the program could be the same.

Comment: Thanks, but the size of my array is not really 10. I want to malloc it on the heap

Comment: Why do you want to malloc it on the heap? If it's a CONSTANT size, there is no benefit in having it on the heap - just more complications.

Comment: Then please try `struct A *b;` and malloc for the same inside the `main` function prior to the loop. Please do ensure that the memory is freed before main ends.

Comment: @Mats Petersson: Are you sure even if the size of the array is so big, there is no benefit?

Comment: You still need whatever amount of bytes to store it. If it's not initialized, it will take up no space in the executable file. But by having a constant address, it probably gives a slight advantage in speed to access. And there is no need to remember to free it, checking if it allocted successfully, etc.

Comment: @Ganesh Why would you need to free anything before the main ends, as everything it is going to be freed anyway?

Comment: @dexter4712345 it is out of habit in embedded systems programming :) Since there was only one function `main`, I referred to the same

Comment: Thank you. Of course it is good to free every malloc, even if it is before exit, just for practice alone.